# Bounds / Approximation to sum of squares of sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can we define any tight upper / lower bound or approximation to the expression,

$\sum_{i = 1}^{N}|x_{i} + y_{i}|^{2}$

in terms of $\sum_{i = 1}^{N} |x_{i}|^{2}$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^{N} |y_{i}|^{2}$, where $x_{i}, y_{i} \in \mathbb{C}, \forall i \in \{1, 2, , \ldots, N\}$.

The bound should be tight enough to represent $\exp \left\{ - \left( \sum_{i = 1}^{N}|x_{i} + y_{i}|^{2} \right) \right\}$ in terms of $\exp \left( - \sum_{i = 1}^{N} |x_{i}|^2 \right)$ and $\exp \left( - \sum_{i = 1}^{N} |y_{i}|^2 \right)$.

Answer (score 1):

We see \begin{align*}\sum^N_{i=1} \lvert x_i + y_i \rvert^2 &= \sum^N_{i=1} \lvert x_i\rvert^2 + x_i \overline{y_i}+ \overline{x_i} y_i + \lvert y_i \rvert^2 \\
&=\sum^N_{i=1} \lvert x_i \rvert^2 + \lvert y_i \rvert^2 + 2 \text{Re}\{\overline{x_i} y_i\}.
\end{align*} However, the real part of a complex number is always less than the magnitude, so $$\sum^N_{i=1} \lvert x_i + y_i \rvert^2 \le \sum^N_{i=1} \lvert x_i\rvert^2 + \lvert y_i \rvert^2 + 2 \lvert x_i \rvert \lvert y_i \rvert.$$ Now we use $ab \le \frac 1 2 (a^2 + b^2)$ which holds for all $a,b \in \mathbb R$. Thus $$\sum^N_{i=1} \lvert x_i + y_i \rvert^2 \le \sum^{N}_{i=1} \lvert x_i \rvert^2 + \lvert y_i \rvert^2 + 2\cdot \frac 1 2 (\lvert x_i \rvert^2 + \lvert y_i \rvert^2 ) = 2\left(\sum^N_{i=1} \lvert x_i \rvert^2 + \sum^N_{i=1} \lvert y_i \rvert^2 \right).$$ This bound is tight. To see this, you can make $\text{Re}(\overline{x_i} y_i) \le \lvert x_i \rvert \lvert y_i \rvert$ an equality by taking $x_i,y_i$ real and positive. You can make $2\lvert x_i \rvert \lvert y_i \rvert \le \lvert x_i \rvert^2 + \lvert y_i \rvert^2$ and equality by taking $x_i = y_i$.

Comment: After edit: This bound will be loose when used with an exponential function.